# Semantic question about the definite article

Tags: articles, definite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a usage of “the” that indicates one out of a group of many?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71755/is-there-a-usage-of-the-that-indicates-one-out-of-a-group-of-many)

The definite article is used when the referent is “uniquely identifiable” to the hearer, as many linguists say.

However, when it is used to express genericness as in this example:

> *The* lion is an animal.

I just don’t think that the noun is referring to a “uniquely identifiable” entity.

As someone whose mother language has no article, I want to know how the definite article can refer both to uniquely identifiable referents and also to generic referents as well.

Could anyone explain?

Native speakers of English understand sentences that use *the* to express genericness even when they haven’t learned the usage, which means that what *the* indicates is ultimately one and only one.

There must be something common between the normal usage of *the* and the generic usage. That’s what I want to know. Telling me what kind of lion would come to mind when seeing a sentence like

> The lion is an animal.

would also help.

Comment: Yes it can have the second function you mention. Cobuild have a 100 page monograph on the many and varied usages of the articles in English.