# Why is it "Hungry Like THE Wolf"?

Tags: differences, articles, lyrics

In the Duran Duran song "Hungry Like the Wolf", the definite article "the" is used instead of the indefinite article "a". Aside from artistic liberty, is there a reason this is done? What does "the wolf" convey as opposed to "a wolf"?

**Lyrical Extract:**

> In touch with the ground
>   I'm on a hunt down after you
>   Smell like I sound I'm lost in a crowd.
>   And I'm **hungry like the wolf**.

Comment: ***The lion*** *(Panthera leo) is one of* **the big cats** *in the genus Panthera and* **a member** of **the family Felidae**.  AND ***The gray wolf*** *or grey wolf (Canis lupus), also known as **the timber wolf** or western wolf, is **a canid** native to the wilderness and remote areas of Eurasia and ...*

Comment: Also related: [Is there a usage of “the” that indicates one out of a group of many?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71755/is-there-a-usage-of-the-that-indicates-one-out-of-a-group-of-many)

Comment: @Mari-LouA That second link was helpful and I think it's what's being done in this instance.

Comment: It's a lyric -- a poem.  The song writer is free to use whatever terms he wishes.  He felt "the" worked better to get across his meaning (and maintain the rhyme and rhythm).

Comment: @ELU community. This is not a duplicate, because it is not certain that Duran Duran is using *the wolf* as a generic noun phrase. In addition, even if that is the case, the linked questions fail to mention that *a wolf* and *wolves* are also generic noun phrases. Thus whether or not it is a generic noun phrase is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

First, in every single lyrics website that I've checked, it is *the hunt*, not *a hunt*. (Overall, these websites contradict each other as to the lyrics: some websites omit the word *down*, and one finds other discrepancies (*the earth is a fire* vs *the earth is afire*, etc.)

Next, the band/songwriter(s) wanted to use the  definite noun phrase *the wolf* in the simile *hungry like the wolf* instead of an indefinite noun phrase (*a wolf*). Since we cannot read the minds of the songwriters, we can't say or explain why they made this choice. The alternative *hungry like a wolf* is grammatical and, in at least one sense, the expected phrasing.

We don't even know if *the wolf* refers to a 'generic wolf', an actual wolf, or some other kind of wolf. Apparently the lyrics are based in the story of Little Red Riding Hood.

However, we do have the text as it is, and the text is *Hungry Like the Wolf*.  This is used not only in the chorus, but as the title.  In short, to state the obvious, *hungry like the wolf* uses a definite noun phrase, which (by definition and by description) is *definite* as opposed to *indefinite*.

Sometimes, the use of definite language is greatly desired over the use of indefinite language. For instance, if a gal I'm interested in  says, 'Let's go out to a movie sometime', that's indefinite and I'm not going to set my hopes on such a statement. But if she  says, 'Let's go see the 9:30 showing  of *Title of Movie* on Wednesday of next week', she's speaking definitely and that's a date, as we say, set in stone.

In the song, using *hungry like **the wolf*** is simply definite versus the indefinite *hungry like **a wolf***. One could use *a wolf* throughout the song. The same for *the forest* in the line *stalked in **the forest** too close to hide*. One could use *a forest* there as well. Just as 'the forest' talks about a definite forest (such as the one the hunted person is in), 'the wolf' talks about a definite wolf, such as the one that is hunting the person. In this sense, this song is about a definite forest and a definite wolf. Since, grammatically, that which is *definite* is also *specific* (but note in passing, not vice versa), the song is about a specific forest and a specific wolf. In narrating a story, if we read this song as a narrative, the use of specific items makes the story 'up close and personal'. It's not just any old forest we're talking about, but *the forest*, and it's not just any old wolf, but *the wolf* that's pursuing you. (The song gets even more up close and personal with its choice of other determiners: '*your* skin' and '*my* heat', for example.)

Or consider another example of the difference between a definite and indefinite noun phrase: you and I are standing on the edge of  a forest and I suddenly yell: *Watch out for a wolf!*, well, you might take me as being mad, since in that context, that statement has little applicable meaning. You might ask me what I mean and what wolf  I'm talking about. But if I suddenly scream *Watch out for the wolf!* you're probably more apt, if you're a native speaker, to perceive you are in  immediate danger of encountering a definite wolf. You might ask 'What wolf?' but by then it might be too late.

I said earlier we might expect the wording *hungry like a wolf*. This is because it parallels such popular simile-idioms as *hungry as a bear* and *hungry as a church mouse*. In fact, a *[Dictionary of Similes](http://www.bartleby.com/161/1252.html)* (1916) lists a dozen other such similes, including *hungry as a wolf*.

SIDEBAR:
Pointing out that *the wolf* can be a generic noun phrase doesn't say much, since (a) we don't know whether Duran Duran is using it as a generic noun phrase, (b)  there are three types of generic noun phrases, and both *a wolf* and *wolves* can be generic noun phrases  (see [Re: A question about the generic use of articles](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), by John Lawler, and (c)  it occurs in a simile, in symbolic language, in a song, inspired by the tale Little Red Riding Hood.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question, or commentary?

Comment: @AndrewLeach It is an answer. I've removed the opening 'commentary'. But I don't know an effective way to declaim that this question should be reopened, mainly because the linked to answers assume such-and-such is a generic noun phrase, but we cannot assume that here. Indeed the phrase here departs from expected phrasing.